# How would an aircraft visually signal "in distress"?

Tags: emergency, flight-interception

A ship at sea would fly its flag upside down to signal it's in distress. How does a plane or airliner that has no radio or transponder visually signal that it is in distress?

This question: [How do commercial pilots send distress signals?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/2163/how-do-commercial-pilots-send-distress-signals) explains how it is done using a radio or transponder, but how could the message "please don't shoot me down" be relayed visually to a fighter pilot?

Comment: To fly a flag upside down the aircraft would probably have to fly inverted :D "Look at me I'm in distress, I'm inverted" LOL

Comment: A flag upside down? Wouldn't do much good for Romania, France, Belgium and Japan, would it?

Comment: It seems like there are multiple questions here. Are you meaning specifically to ask about how to communicate with a fighter pilot who is escorting you if you've lost your radios or are you asking more generally about how to signal distress. It would be better to focus the question on one or the other, as this seems to be causing confusion in the answers.

Comment: @Mast That's some very impressive flag knowledge. Username checks out.

Comment: I'm trying to imagine a situation in which "please don't shoot me down" would ever be a useful message ;-D

Comment: I remember a stolen MIG indicating a desire to land by dropping its landing gear at a South Korean base, but that wasn't distress.

Comment: Annex IV of the "International Regulations for Preventing Collisions at Sea" (a.k.a., "COLREGS") lists fifteen different things that the crew of a ship can do to signal a dire emergency.  Flying an up-side down flag is not one of them.

Comment: I would presume that every aircraft wants to communicate that particular message.

Comment: Once we got into trouble on a French ship, so we flew our flag upside down.  Nobody helped.  Then we flagged British and had another problem.  We were ignored by 11 ships until a boat of British vexillologists stopped to help.   Then we flagged American, ditto.   Everybody stopped!

Comment: Presumably, a plane could plummet towards the ground at high speeds to signal distress.

Comment: Have you tried pleading and praying? At this point of time, if you do not know how to follow the military aircraft and cannot communicate using radio or you lights a prayer is all I would have left.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

For the US, the [FAA's *Intercept Procedures*](https://www.faa.gov/news/safety_briefing/2015/media/Intercept-Procedures.pdf) list several things a pilot can indicate without radios:

- Acknowledge instructions: rock wings, flash nav lights
- Unable to land at indicated airport: flash landing lights
- Cannot comply: switch all lights on and off at *regular* intervals
- In distress: switch all lights on and off at *irregular* intervals

Comment: Are the any other ways if those cannot be performed?

Comment: Being creative: If near enough, sheets of paper with one big letter on each? A torch or mirror? Cellphone if low enough (normally a nogo, but if in distress...).

Comment: @Peter Yes a satellite phone.

Comment: @Muze Handheld radio, mobile phone, gestures, Morse code with a flashlight, writing in large letters on a sheet of paper, and who knows what else. I'm guessing that people will get creative in that situation :-)

Comment: I dimly remember that flying in a triangular pattern is supposed to be a distress signal for ATC radar.

Comment: @JohnK See [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/26261/62) :-)

Comment: Although not a commercial pilot example, during [Operation Frequent Wind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Frequent_Wind) (US evacuation from Saigon during Vietnam War) *"(...)the pilot of an RVNAF Cessna O-1 dropped a note on the deck of the carrier. The note read "Can you move these helicopter to the other side, I can land on your runway, I can fly 1 hour more, we have enough time to move. Please rescue me. Major Buang, Wife and 5 child."*

Comment: @Peter I'm guessing you're in the UK? The thought of signaling with a [_torch_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torch) while flying an airplane sounds like a very bad idea in American English. - haha

Comment: For your convenience „flashlight“. I‘m not a native speaker.

Comment: @Peter haha - Yeah, I knew what you meant. It just caused a funny mental picture. I suppose flames in the cockpit would be very effective at signalling distress, though.

Comment: I seen footage of planes in the 2WW waggling/rocking their wings to mean they're in need of help + don't shoot. In more modern films where a 'goodie' is flying back home in a stolen enemy aircraft - flying on a steady path, and rocking wings has been used to portray the 'don't shoot' - but obviously that's films, so pinch of salt needed.

Comment: @Peter "torch" is actually correct in British English; "flashlight" in American English :)

Comment: Oh dear.  So the trigger-happy interceptor pilot is supposed to know if the lights are flashing at a "regular" or "irregular" interval?  Maybe the pilot being intercepted should hold up a box of Pepto-Bismol or Immodium.

Answer (score 10):

ICAO describes the following distress signals in Annex 2 (Rules of the Air):

> The following signals, used either together or separately, mean that  grave  and  imminent  danger  threatens,  and  immediate assistance  is  requested:
>
> a)  a  signal  made  by  radiotelegraphy  or  by  any  other signalling   method   consisting   of   the   group   SOS (. . . — — — . . .  in  the  Morse  Code);
>
> b)  a radiotelephony distress signal consisting of the spoken word MAYDAY;
>
> c)  a distress message sent via data link which transmits the intent  of  the  word  MAYDAY;
>
> d)  rockets or shells throwing red lights, fired one at a time at short intervals;
>
> e)  a parachute flare showing a red light.

Note that a) mentions "any other signalling method", which could, for instance, be flashing aircraft lights. d) and e) require no radio or transponder.

In addition, the following *urgency* signals exist:

> The   following   signals,   used   either   together   or separately,  mean  that  an  aircraft  wishes  to  give  notice  of  difficulties  which  compel  it  to  land  without  requiring  immediate assistance:
>
> a)  the  repeated  switching  on  and  off  of  the  landing  lights;
>
> b)  the  repeated  switching  on  and  off  of  the  navigation lights  in  such  manner  as  to  be  distinct  from  flashing navigation lights

Comment: Are there any signals which could be sent from an aircraft which lost all electrical systems? (I'm assuming most planes don't carry flares or rockets.)

Comment: @Skyler In that case, rocking the wings could still be useful on short range.

Comment: @Skyler: "...a [SOS] signal made by radiotelegraphy _or by any other signalling method_..." -- Interceptors will attempt to get a look into the cockpit for an idea of what's going on. A torch or smartphone light will do nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Commercial flights are very regular throughout the world. One sure fire way to signal "don't shoot me I'm in distress" would be to fly low, and slow. a 737 at 5000 AGL would certainly signal something is wrong (most of the time) and would certainly get someone's attention.

Finding an airport and following the failed comms procedures and making a landing there would also be a sure sign that you needed help.

Remember you don't need a transponder and radio to land, and if you're doing something unusual, generally speaking, everyone else gets out of the way. Also, it would depend on the kind of distress your in. With no radio and no transponder, you probably have a pretty big electrical issue and need to land right away. So land.

Comment: Your advice goes against the procedure linked to in Pondlife's answer, which says: "Do not adjust your altitude, heading, or airspeed until directed to by the intercepting aircraft."

Comment: Those rules are for being intercepted. i.e. a fighter escort. I was speaking to letting others know you're in trouble.

Comment: Yeah, I think the question isn't very clear about exactly what it's asking for. This seems to answer the title question, but not the part in the body about, "how could the message "please don't shoot me down" be relayed visually to a fighter pilot?" That part would indeed imply being escorted. Having said that, if your goal is to indicate that you are not a threat and should not be shot down, flying a 737 at 5,000 ft probably isn't the best first move. It will signal distress alright, but not so much the "Please don't shoot me down" part.

Comment: I think the downvoted are for suggesting flying a 737 at 5000 ft to get attention. While it would get you attention, I think it’s also a good way of getting shot down.

Comment: @reirab Why would you need to signal to your own escorts to not shoot you down? You'd signal that to interceptors if anything.

Comment: @Kapten-N: I think the question here is to _turn_ the _interceptors_ (which would have to take into account the possibility of a 9/11 type of situation) into _escorts_ (i.e. pilots who no longer wonder whether they will have to shoot you down, and instead attempt to help, e.g. by relaying morsed light signals to ground).

Comment: @DevSolar Yes. That was my point exactly. You're trying to signal interceptors, not escorts.